# Fluctuation in vs of

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between "fluctuation in" and "fluctuation of"?

For instance,

> There is no fluctuation of the singularity location.

and

> There is no fluctuation in the singularity location.

Do these sentences convey the same idea?

Comment: Do you mean that the location of the singularity is fixed? Or do you mean that things within the singularity location are fixed?

Comment: Singularity is just a point, it does not have any constituent parts. I mean that it remains in a fixed position (e.g., when certain parameters are varied).

Comment: No, because it's fluctuation in the singularity or fluctuation in the/a quantum field.

Answer (score 1):

With this construction there is not always a difference but difference is sometimes possible. Consider:

*There is no fluctuation of the population.*
Implies that the population (total number of people in a country, for exanple) is constant.
Such a usage permits the number of men to change so long as the number of women changes the same amount in the opposite sense.

*There is no fluctuation in the population*
Although often taken as synonymous with the first case, it may also imply that there is no change in (= within the constituent parts of) the population.
This usage does not permit even the numbers of women and men to change, and the total population remains constant.

In your example, the possibility of such differeces is conditioned by the nature of a "singularity location", a term whose meaning needs definition before a definite answer can be decided.

{It is easy but unnecessary to complicate this argumemt with secondary issues such as the presence of children in the population.}

Answer (score 0):

With the fluctuation  *in* location multiple meanings are possible:

1. the location is a point and its coordinates are changing and doing so irregularly:
2. The location is not a point but has extension and the shape of the area is changing irregularly.
3. The location is not a point but has extension and within the boundaries of the location some sort of fluctuation (of something *within* the area) is happening.

With the flucation *of* location two  meanings are possible:

1. the location is a point and its coordinates are changing and doing so irregularly.
2. The location is not a point but has extension and the shape is changing irregularly.

Which of these possible meanings is being negated is ambiguous without further clarification.